# What does !head do in python and NumPy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

Can you tell how things are working in In[13]?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with Python or NumPy specifically; that's a feature of `ipython` to run external programs, in this case, the `head` utility from the standard suite of *NIX command line utilities. `head -4` just reads the first four lines of the file provided and echoes them to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Using **"!"** means that you want to call a system command. If you are on a **Linux/Unix system** (Google Colab uses such a system for instance) **then you can call Linux/Unix commands directly using "!"**. Looks like you are using a Windows system and the command "head" **does not exist as a command in Windows**. Assuming that you are using a locally hosted **Jupyter Notebook**, then it is running on a **Windows system**.

The **head command** itself is a command-line utility for outputting the **first part of files** given to it **via standard input**. It writes results **to standard output**. By default head returns the **first ten lines** of **each file** that it is given.

Comment: Not sure where you get the idea the OP is on Windows. They don't say they tried the command at all. And even if it failed, it could easily be because they're not using IPython.